# blur edges function in cs50

Tags: c, cs50

i know the code looks ugly but cleaning is for later i want it to work first then i could work on the clean design

i run it on check50 and it says that it can't blur edges, i try applying the same technique in a test file with constant values of red, green, blue and it works well

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            blurcorner(i,j,height,width,image,copy);
            bluredge(i,j,height,width,image,copy);
            image[i][j] = copy[i][j];
        }
    }
    return;
}


////////
void blurcorner (int i, int j, int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width],RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width])
{
    if (i == height - 1  && j == width - 1)
    {
        int redav = (image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j-1].rgbtRed + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtRed) / 4;
        copy[i][j].rgbtRed = redav;
        int greenav = (image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtGreen) / 4;
        copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = greenav;
        int blueav = (image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtBlue) / 4;
        copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = blueav;
    }
    else if (i == height - 1  && j == 0)
    {
        int redav = (image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j+1].rgbtRed + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtRed) / 4;
        copy[i][j].rgbtRed = redav;
        int greenav = (image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j+1].rgbtGreen + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtGreen) / 4;
        copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = greenav;
        int blueav = (image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j+1].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtBlue) / 4;
        copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = blueav;
    }
    else if (i == 0  && j == 0)
    {
        int redav = (image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j+1].rgbtRed + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtRed) / 4;
        copy[i][j].rgbtRed = redav;
        int greenav = (image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j+1].rgbtGreen + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtGreen) / 4;
        copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = greenav;
        int blueav = (image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j+1].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtBlue) / 4;
        copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = blueav;
    }
    else if (i == 0  && j == width - 1)
    {
        int redav = (image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j-1].rgbtRed + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtRed) / 4;
        copy[i][j].rgbtRed = redav;
        int greenav = (image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtGreen) / 4;
        copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = greenav;
        int blueav = (image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtBlue) / 4;
        copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = blueav;
    }
}

void bluredge (int i, int j, int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width],RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width])
{
    if (i == 0 && j > 0 && j < width - 1)
    {
        int redav = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j-1].rgbtRed + image[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed + image[i+1][j].rgbtRed + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed + image[i][j+1].rgbtRed) / 6;
        copy[i][j].rgbtRed = redav;
        int greenav = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + image[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen + image[i+1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j+1].rgbtGreen) / 6;
        copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = greenav;
        int blueav = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j+1].rgbtBlue) / 6;
        copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = blueav;
    }
    else if (i == height - 1 && j > 0 && j < width - 1)
    {
        int redav = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j-1].rgbtRed + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed + image[i-1][j].rgbtRed + image[i-1][j+1].rgbtRed + image[i][j+1].rgbtRed) / 6;
        copy[i][j].rgbtRed = redav;
        int greenav = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][j+1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j+1].rgbtGreen) / 6;
        copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = greenav;
        int blueav = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][j+1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j+1].rgbtBlue) / 6;
        copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = blueav;
    }
    else if (i > 0 && i < height - 1 && j == width - 1)
    {
        int redav = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i-1][j].rgbtRed + image[i+1][j].rgbtRed + image[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed) / 6;
        copy[i][j].rgbtRed = redav;
        int greenav = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i+1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen) / 6;
        copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = greenav;
        int blueav = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue) / 6;
        copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = blueav;
    }
    else if (i > 0 && i < height - 1 && j == 0)
    {
        int redav = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i-1][j].rgbtRed + image[i+1][j].rgbtRed + image[i+1]
[j+1].rgbtRed + image[i][j+1].rgbtRed + image[i-1][j+1].rgbtRed) / 6;
        copy[i][j].rgbtRed = redav;
        int greenav = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i+1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j+1].rgbtGreen + image[i-1][j+1].rgbtGreen) / 6;
        copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = greenav;
        int blueav = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j+1].rgbtBlue + image[i-1][j+1].rgbtBlue) / 6;
        copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = blueav;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

before you start hating on me the blur corners function is similar and it worked

i tried changing how i adress each pixel many times but it didnt work

here is the error i get:

```
:( blur correctly filters pixel on edge
    expected "80 95 105\n", not "80 95 108\n"
```

i think the problem is with the blue

Comment: Aren't you also supposed to blur middle pixels, not just edges and corners?

Comment: `image[i][j] = copy[i][j];` you aren't supposed to copy back to the original until the whole blur is complete.

Comment: i am supposed to and i'm gonna do it after i figure out the edges, and i don't think it will make a difference wich before wich since we don't use the blurred pixel in blurring other pixels

Comment: i know but the check50 gives a report about every kind of pixel so it tells me that the corners are done even though i didn't blur the rest yet so the copy line is there untill i'm done

Comment: Of course it makes a difference, because you are blurring pixels with neighbours that were already blurred. All the blurring must be done with the original pixel values. With your idea, you won't get the same result if you scan in a different direction.

Comment: the blurred pixels go in the copy version while the original pixels are blurred using their original surroundings

Comment: Look more closely. You copy the blurred pixel back to the original image immediately. That will be a neighbour of the next pixel you blur.

Comment: moved the line out of the loop and made other loops for it but still no difference

Comment: Integer division will truncate, not round... It'll be small, but it's there. Maybe that's why so many other samples posted here use floating point?

Comment: @Fe2O3 The other answers do _not_ need FP. They're semi-broken. Today, you were commenting on: [CS50 Problem Set 4 Filter (less). I keep getting Seg Fault errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75317106/5382650). See chux's last comment about how to do rounding with `int`. Also, I had put a link there to some of my blur answers. The issues with this cs50 problem are usually less about the final division and more about handling the edge cases correctly

Comment: @CraigEstey Thank you. Muddied in this OP code is integer division. I thought it worth mention.

Comment: Post the code for `blurcorner` and ?? `blurmiddle` too.

Comment: added blurcorner , but i didn't write blurmiddle yet

Comment: You have indexing typos in the second block of that, `else if (i == height - 1  && j == 0)` where you use both `i-1` and `i+1`.

Comment: check the latest edit

Comment: you mentioned and error thats not actually an error cause this function works just fine if i needed help with it i'd posted it first i need hwlp in the bluredges function

Answer (score 0):

in the blue of the first if in the bluredge:

```
int blueav = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j+1].rgbtBlue) / 6;
    copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = blueav;
```

the value
`image[i+1][j+1]` is there twice, one of them needs to be edited into `image[i+1][j-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Because it wouldn't be right to write working code for you that you hadn't already tried to write for yourself, the following is to illustrate the advantages of pausing the "advance" to improve on the technique. Here is a version of most of your `blurcorner()` showing how you could make your code more readable and robust. Trying to find an errant '+' that should be a '-' in the OP code is tantamount to looking for a needle in a haystack. Perhaps you will consider this before spending too much time struggling to make a poor implementation work.

```
void blurcorner( int i, int j, int height, int width,
    RGBTRIPLE image[][width], RGBTRIPLE copy[][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE u0, u1, u2, u3;

    u0 = image[i][j];
    if (i == 0 ) { // Top
        u1 = image[ i + 1 ][ j ];
        int off_j = ( j == 0 ) ? j + 1 : j - 1;
        u2 = image[ i     ][ off_j ];
        u3 = image[ i + 1 ][ off_j ];
    } else { // Bottom
        // left as an exercise
    }

    int red = u0.rgbtRed   + u1.rgbtRed   + u2.rgbtRed   + u3.rgbtRed  ;
    int grn = u0.rgbtGreen + u1.rgbtGreen + u2.rgbtGreen + u3.rgbtGreen;
    int blu = u0.rgbtBlue  + u1.rgbtBlue  + u2.rgbtBlue  + u3.rgbtBlue ;

    copy[i][j].rgbtRed   = red / 4;
    copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = grn / 4;
    copy[i][j].rgbtBlue  = blu / 4;
}
```

(The integer division problem has not been addressed here.)